# Select rows that are not present in the table based on criteria

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables student table and fee table:

First Table (Student):

| std_id | std_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |

Second Table(Fee):

| fid | std_id | amount | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 | 2022-07 |
| 2 | 2 | 500 | 2022-07 |
| 3 | 4 | 500 | 2022-07 |
| 4 | 1 | 500 | 2022-08 |
| 5 | 2 | 500 | 2022-08 |

I want to fetch rows of those students from fee table who are not paid amount based on month. For Example want to fetch rows of those students from second table who did not pay fee in 2022-07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion. Use proper date data type to store dates , `2022-07` is not a valid date data type, you will save a lot of pain for the future.

As per the question, one way using exists:

```
select s.std_name
from Student s 
where not  exists (select 1 from Fee f where s.std_id=f.std_id and f.Month='2022-07');
```

Another way using left join:

```
select s.std_name
from Student s 
left join Fee f on s.std_id=f.std_id and f.Month='2022-07' 
where f.Month is null ;
```

You will benefit from the following indexes

```
key std_month(`std_id`,`Month`)   --- > on Fee     table 
key `std_id`(`std_id`)            --- > on Student table
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecd96397f42659ba45e8e848e42cd90c